# How to Run Cron job or Command in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5

I have a requirement that i have to run a cron job or say a laravel 5 in every two minute. This command or job will receive some data from controller and then insert into the database, if not receive then it should skip or insert dummy data just for testing purpose.

I know how to create command, but stuck how to pass data from controller or receive data in command. I really need help in this regard.

Please friend help me, i need to finish it as soon as possible. If someone require further clarification, please let me know.

Comment: How are you trying to pass arguments to the script ?

Comment: I don't know anything about passing or creating the command.

Comment: Can you please explain your scenario? From where will the controller get the data? who will feed it every 2 min?

Comment: Actually we have our raw data stored in datas table. Now our requirement is to check every single record which we are received per second or two second to match and if matched then copy that record from datas table to new table. This task need to be done in every second or two second. Right now I an able to do that using controller, but that need to be done in background like using cron job.